# Why does the super() not showing error though not given in first line?

Tags: java

Why does the super keyword not showing error though not given in first line

Comment: Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints to help you write better questions in future - and edit this question to show the code you don't understand.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: I love that there is a tinyurl for that now

Comment: @Alastair: I created the tinyurl straight after writing the post :)

Answer (score 2):

It does for me:

```
class Superclass
{
}

class Subclass extends Superclass
{
    Subclass()
    {
        System.out.println();
        super();
    }
}
```

Compiling gives an error of:

```
Test.java:10: call to super must be first statement in constructor
        super();
             ^
1 error
```

Please show a similar short but complete program with it *not* giving an error. Note that I'm assuming you really have got `super();` rather than, say, `super.foo();` which is just a call to the superclass implementation of `foo();` and can appear anywhere in a method or constructor.

Answer (score 1):

`super(args...)` is required for the constructor's at first line.

`super.property` can be used anywhere in the code

Answer (score 0):

Then you might be making a method call and not Sayin `super()` inside constructor.. for instance..

```
class Superclass
{
public void f1(){

}
}

class Subclass extends Superclass
{
    Subclass()
    {
        System.out.println();
        super.f1();
    }
}
```

The above code works fine...