# Why does super keyword sometimes does not throw an error although it is not used as the first statement?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does the super() not showing error though not given in first line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7036299/why-does-the-super-not-showing-error-though-not-given-in-first-line)

Can we use super keyword to call instance variables anywhere in the code

Comment: Your question title doesn't match your body (and it's longer than the body as well!). Please fix this and give a sample of what you think should "throw an error".

Comment: @Aravind you might be confusing the use of super to invoke a superclass constructor with other uses of the keyword.  Example code will help a great deal.

Comment: Please edit your *previous* question instead of just repeating it.

Comment: @Jon previous question has already been answered

Comment: @Jigar: It's not *at all* clear to me that Aravind has actually seen the previous answers, or that he's trying to ask anything significantly different here. He's also clearly not learned from the requests for more clarity (and code) in the comments on the previous question. Editing that question for clarity would have been better than asking this one.

Comment: @Jon Absolutely Agree. but summing yours + mine answer has undoubtedly answered his question

Comment: he created a whole new user for this one

Answer (score 0):

> Why does super keyword sometimes does not throw an error although it
>   is not used as  the first statement?

You are not required to write ***super*** ***keyword*** at the start of constructor. What require is calling super class constructor that is ***super()***. The super keyword is used to refer to superclass and super() or super(args) is used to call constructor of superclass. May be you are mixing **super keyword** and **super constructor**.

Answer (score 0):

You may be confusing a call to `super` in a constructor, which must be the first statement, with the use of `super` in other methods. For example:

```
@Override
public void doStuff(String input) {
    //do a few things
    super.doStuff(input);  //call to overridden method - can be anywhere, and is optional
    //do some more things
}
```